# Matlab Recursion Loop

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, recursion

I need to create a loop to answer **part c** of the [image]following linear algebra question. I'm new to Matlab so this is extremely confusing. I'm not sure how to make a loop that "counts" from 0-25 in order to generate a new matrix for each value. If someone could help me out it'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do the loop:

```
A = [1.52, -.7; .56, .4];
x = zeros(2,26);
x(:,1) = [0;1];
for i = 1:25
    x(:,i+1) = A*x(:,i);
end
```

Comment: I think this loop implies that the matrix x goes from [0;1] to [0;2] to [0;3] etc. When it should be that xnew is A*[0;1], and the next xnew is A*the previous xnew.

Comment: You should be able to run the code as I've written it now.  After you run it, check what $x$ looks like